# Reset input field after adding an item to array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a crud app using an array. After I add a item to the array, the html input field does not clear/reset. I dont think angular has a reset method because I could not find anything online. How can I clear the input field after adding an item?

Here is my code:

**app.component.html**

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Angular CRUD</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form-inline custom-centered" name="itemForm">
      <label for="item">Add an Item:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Value" id="Value" #item>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="create(item.value)" style="width: 80px;">Add</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of collection">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <button  class="btn btn-info btn-sm mr-1">Edit</button>
        <button (click)="deleteItem(item)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  collection: any = [];

  create(item: any) {
    this.collection.push({
      name: item
    });
  }

  deleteItem(item: any) {
    this.collection.splice(item, 1);
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide me please, Thank you

Comment: I have a working version of the other question you just asked, but deleted, if you reopen that question I can post my solution!

Comment: @Stoobish Okay will do, I am in the process of learning the fundamentals first. That is why I followed that approach instead of using reactive forms. But thought id might as well look into it now. But Please provide a solution if you can, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has reset() method in reactive forms. But here you are not using reactive form, so here the way to reset the input is, replace your method with this -

```
(click)="create(item.value); item.value = ''"
```

If your form is large, then reactive form is recommended. In this example, what you are using is fine.

[Your working example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-77adlc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: That works, thank you. I will be using reactive forms once I start using larger forms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wrote it in there

```
  create() {
    this.collection.push({
      name: ''
    });
  }
```